# if else in javascript counter timer

Tags: php, javascript, if-statement

Im using a small script to display the amount of time since a given datetime value (passed from PHP query).

The script is as follows:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
TargetDate = "<?php echo $dti3; ?>";
FinishMessage = "done"
BackColor = "white";
ForeColor = "black";
CountActive = true;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days %%H%%:%%M%%:%%S%% ";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"  language="JavaScript" src="time.js"></script>
```

and time.js is

```
function calcage(secs, num1, num2) {
  s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
  if (LeadingZero && s.length < 2)
  s = "0" + s;
 return  s;
 }

 function CountBack(secs) {
 if (secs < 0) {
 document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = FinishMessage;
 return;
 }
 DisplayStr = DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g, calcage(secs,86400,100000));
 DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, calcage(secs,3600,24));
 DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g, calcage(secs,60,60));
 DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g, calcage(secs,1,60));

 document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = DisplayStr;
 if (CountActive)
setTimeout("CountBack(" + (secs+CountStepper) + ")", SetTimeOutPeriod);
}

 function putspan(backcolor, forecolor) {
 document.write("<span id='cntdwn'></span>");
 }

if (typeof(BackColor)=="undefined")
 BackColor = "white";
if (typeof(ForeColor)=="undefined")
ForeColor= "#2A8827";
if (typeof(TargetDate)=="undefined")
 TargetDate = "12/31/2020 05:00:00";
if (typeof(DisplayFormat)=="undefined")
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% days, %%H%% hours, %%M%% minutes, %%S%% seconds.";
if (typeof(CountActive)=="undefined")
 CountActive = true;
if (typeof(FinishMessage)=="undefined")
FinishMessage = "no data";
 if (typeof(CountStepper)!="number")
  CountStepper = +1;
if (typeof(LeadingZero)=="undefined")
 LeadingZero = true;


CountStepper = Math.ceil(CountStepper);
if (CountStepper == 0)
 CountActive = false;
var SetTimeOutPeriod = (Math.abs(CountStepper)-1)*1000 + 1000;
putspan(BackColor, ForeColor);
var dthen = new Date(TargetDate);
var dnow = new Date();
if(CountStepper>0)
  ddiff = new Date(dnow-dthen);
else
  ddiff = new Date(dthen-dnow);
gsecs = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
 CountBack(gsecs);
```

I want to display the time since $dti3 as %%H%%:%%M%%:%%S%% if this is less than 24 hours, otherwise display just the number of days with some text. Ie:

23 hours since date displays as : "23:00:00"
but 25 hours displays as: "more than one day"
and 49 hours displays as "more than two days"
etc...

I imagine this will require an if else statement somewhere but im not much of a JS coder (yet - im working on it!) so im not sure the best way to achieve this.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Many thanks.

Comment: don't tag questions with irrelevant languages please.

Comment: It's hard to understand what's going on.  You should provide a working example on a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/  Hardcode example values wherever your php is called should do.

Comment: Dagon, is php a completely irrelevant tag? The datetime is being passed from php, there is php in the code, and the best way to tackle this answer may turn out to be in the way it is passed, i dont know yet - but irrelevant seems a little unfair. cereal77killer, sure i will put something on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few suggestions.

First, when you're developing this kind of code, separate the PHP and JavaScript completely. Don't try to even think about them at the same time. The two languages don't know anything about each other. Your JavaScript code can only "see" what is available to it in the browser, and that isn't PHP.

Do a View Source of your test page and you will see that there is no PHP in it. What *is* there is what your PHP code *generates*. And that's what you should be looking at and thinking about when you're writing and debugging you JavaScript code—the actual web page that's downloaded to the browser, not the PHP code that generates it.

Next, if you're new to JavaScript, you may want to consider starting by trying out some existing code to format times in the past like you want. A couple of time formatting libraries I would start with are [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and the [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) jQuery plugin. Study the source code for both of these for useful tips, and if neither one does exactly what you want, see which is closer and try modifying it to your needs. (There are probably other similar libraries worth looking at too; these are just a couple that I'm familiar with.)

Of course there's nothing wrong with writing this code yourself either, but it can really help to see how other people have tackled a similar problem.

BTW, if you display times in the past in the "time ago" format down to the second, then you had better add some code to your page to *update* those times every second. Without updating, you can get away with saying "4 hours ago" and probably with saying "3 hours and 45 minutes ago", but if you say "2 hours, 30 minutes, and 17 seconds ago" you had better be updating that in real time or it won't look right to people. (I'm not talking about whether it's formatted like 2:30:17 or the longer form I used here—I used the longer form for emphasis. When you display seconds you greatly increase the expectation that this is a realtime display.)

Now a few tips on your JavaScript code.

- You need to put `var` in front every place that you create a variable. For example, the `s = ...` at the beginning of your `calcage()` function should be `var s = ...`. Otherwise your variable `s` is a *global* variable, and you don't want that.
- The convention in JavaScript is to use an initial capital letter only on constructors (functions intended for use with the `new` keyword). Variable names and ordinary function names use `namesLikeThis`, not `NamesLikeThis`. This is only a convention, not a rule, but you would do well to follow it.
- `typeof` is an operator, not a function, and the modern convention is to leave out the parentheses in expressions like `typeof(BackColor)=="undefined"`. Instead, add some whitespace around the `==` operator: `typeof backColor == "undefined"`.
- Please, clean up your indentation. It is all over the place right now and makes the code much harder to follow than it could be. There are numerous JavaScript code beautifiers you could use, or just get in the habit of doing it properly as you go along. It isn't difficult at all, especially if you use a code editor with good support for indenting and similar features. What editor are you using now?
- Your `putspan()` function uses `document.write()`, and the place where this function is called is buried in the middle of some other setup code. There is probably a better way to do this. For example, what if you want *two* of these time-in-the-past displays in your page, not just one?